# How to factorize $a(y) := xy^{3}+xy^{2}+(x+1)y+x \in GF(2)[x]_{x^{2}+x+1}[y]$

Tags: factoring

Could someone please help me to find irreducible factors of $a(y) := xy^{3}+xy^{2}+(x+1)y+x \in GF(2)[x]_{x^{2}+x+1}[y]$?

In $GF(2)[x]_{x^{2}+x+1}[y]$, we have $0,1,x,x+1$. So we use these in $a(y)$ one after the other:
$0:x⋅0^{3}+x⋅0^{2}+(x+1)⋅0+x=x$  => not a root
$1:x⋅1^{3}+x⋅1^{2}+(x+1)⋅1+x=x+x+x+1+x=4x+1=1$ => not a root
$x:x⋅x^{3}+x⋅x^{2}+(x+1)⋅x+x=x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+x=x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}$

But I don't understand what should I do with $x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}$ now?
I can factorize it into $x^{2}⋅(x^{2}+x+1)$ but how can I understand that x is a root ot not?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint: $x^2$ is $x+1$, so mod $2$ we have $x^2+x+1$ equal zero (by construction).

Comment: Does $GF(2)[x]_{x^{2}+x+1}$ denote  $GF(2)[x]$ localised at the element $x^{2}+x+1$ or modulo $x^{2}+x+1$?

Comment: modulo $x^{2}+x+1$

Comment: @hardmath,thank you very much, I was able to understand the problem now.

Comment: I invite you to try your hand at posting the completed Answer, if you have the energy.

Comment: @hardmath, just one more question. We know that $x^{2}$ is $x+1$ because we have $GF(2)[x]_{x^{2}+x+1}[y]$, so mod $x^{2}+x+1$? And if we have mod $x^{2}+1$, then we would use $x^{2}=1$ in our calculations?

Comment: @pramort:  Well, that's partly how it would work.  In the original problem working modulo $x^2 + x + 1$ gave you a *finite field* of order $4$.  That's because $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$.  $x^2+1 = (x+1)^2$ mod $2$, so it's not irreducible.  So changing to work mod $x^2 + 1$ means the coefficients you'd get do not form a field but rather a ring with zero divisors.

Comment: @hardmath, Sorry, I didn't mention that I would take GF(3) then. $x^{2}+1$ over GF(3) is irreducible. It would then be a field. Would it be true to say that $x^{2}=1$? So, I would use $x^{2}=1$ and not $x^{2}=x+1$. I'm just trying to understand how we get $x^{2}=x+1$ in the first problem.

Comment: Well, if $x^2+1=0$ mod $3$, then $x^2=-1$ mod $3$, so it's a little different.

Answer (score 1):

@hardmath, I'll try :-)

In $GF(2)[x]_{x^{2}+x+1}[y]$, we have $0,1,x,x+1$. So we use these in a(y) one after the other:

- $0:x⋅0^{3}+x⋅0^{2}+(x+1)⋅0+x=x$ => not a root.
- $1:x⋅1^{3}+x⋅1^{2}+(x+1)⋅1+x=x+x+x+1+x=4x+1=1$ => not a root.
- $x:x⋅x^{3}+x⋅x^{2}+(x+1)⋅x+x=x4+x3+x2+x+x=x4+x3+x2 =0$ => x is a root.
- $x+1:x⋅(x+1)^{3}+x⋅(x+1)^{2}+(x+1)⋅(x+1)+x=x+x+1+x+x=1$ => not a root.

Therefore, we know that $(y+x)$ is one of the factors.

$(xy^{3}+xy^{2}+(x+1)y+x):(y+x)=xy^{2}+y+1$

Again, we use $0,1,x,x+1$ in order to determine whether $xy^{2}+y+1$ is irreducible:

- $0:x⋅0^{2}+0+1=1$ => not a root.
- $1:x⋅1^{2}+1+1=x$ => not a root.
- $x:x⋅x^{2}+x+1=x^{3}+x+1=x$ => not a root.
- $x+1:x(x+1)^{2}+(x+1)+1=x(x^{2}+1)+x=x^{2}=1$ => not a root.

$xy^{2}+y+1$ has no roots, so it is irreducible over GF(2).

Therefore, 
$xy^{3}+xy^{2}+(x+1)y+x=(y+x)⋅(xy^{2}+y+1)$